# Right sidebar overlaps min-width content.

Tags: html, css, sidebar

This question has been asked an awful lot of times here, but I am yet to find a conclusive answer to this.

I'm working to implement right and left 100% height, fixed sidebars in my design. The Left sidebar works great, but the right one floats over the (min-width'd) content when the browser is resized. 
When I set the position of the bars to absolute, it behaves well with horizontal window resizing, but then the sidebars aren't fixed on vertical scroll.

Check out my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wjhzyt0u/17/

(If you resize the window, you can see the right blue bar float over the middle grey content).

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <section id="sidebar-nav">
  </section>

  <section id="content">
      <p>some rad stylin' content</p>
  </section>

  <section id="sidebar-notif">
  </section>

</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 450px; /* dont want to squish the content too much */
}

#sidebar-nav, #sidebar-notif {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background: lightblue;
}
#sidebar-nav {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#sidebar-notif {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#content {
    margin: 0 150px;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

Any help would be very welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

My 'solution' for anyone else looking at a similar situation.

I ended up going with absolutely positioned sidebars (which scale to the size of the middle content), and added the [Waypoint sticky plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) to scroll the sidebar content.

Updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wjhzyt0u/20/

Sticky divs stick to the top of the page on scroll - thus creating the illusion of 100% height sidebars. 
Drawbacks are extra js weight + page load times.. but I'll take it for now.

Changes:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 500px; 
    // removed 100% min-height, which lets the sidebars stretch to 100% height of the content. 
}

#sidebar-nav, #sidebar-notif {
    position: absolute; // changed to absolute from fixed.
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background: lightblue;
}

// added sticky divs to sidebars, which stick to the top of the page on scroll (with help from Waypoints sticky plugin. 
.sticky {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```